# Get microphone ID Android API < 23

Tags: android, microphone

My app measures the environment loudness. To be able to do that I need to identify which microphone user is using, wired, Bluetooth, or embedded one. 
I need an approach that allows me to do that from API 21.

I found out we can do it Using MicrophoneInfo, but it requires API > 28.
Thre is one approach that covers for the app with API > 23 like so:

```
private fun getBuiltInMicDeviceId(context: Context): Int {
        with(context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager) {
            return getDevices(GET_DEVICES_INPUTS).first { it.type == TYPE_BUILTIN_MIC }.id
        }
}
```

But didn't find anything for 21 though. Does anyway could help me out?